# Trouble With Parsing JSON with Perl

Tags: perl, json, parsing

I have a JSON file and I'm trying to parse it in Perl.  So far I have:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

open my $fh, "/Users/arjunnayini/Desktop/map_data.json";   


my @decoded_json = @{decode_json($fh)};
```

But I am getting an error that I have a:
"malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "GLOB(0x100804ed0)") "

I'm fairly certain that the JSON file is formatted properly, so I'm not sure where this is going wrong.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15):

Assuming your call to JSON is correct, you need to slurp the file in first:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $json;
{
  local $/; #enable slurp
  open my $fh, "<", "/Users/arjunnayini/Desktop/map_data.json";
  $json = <$fh>;
} 

my @decoded_json = @{decode_json($json)};
```

Comment: or: local @ARGV = "/Users/arjunnayini/Desktop/map_data.json"; $json = <>;

Comment: Yes there are other ways to slurp in the file first. My example shows a common idiom.